# Pre-filtering for get_next_post() in Wordpress based on current query variables

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type that I am using custom taxonomies on. These taxonomies are used to filter and create an index list of posts.

The question is, once I click on one of these posts from a filtered list, I have a previous and next post link on the page; I'd like these links to respect the filters previously added.

Is there a way to pull the "next matching post" instead of just the next post of the same custom type? It seems that there should be a filter variables option built in, but I can't seem to find it.

It would be nice to do something like:

```
$filter = array("foo"=>"bar","category"=>"something");
$next_post = get_next_post($filter);
```

Obviously this **isn't compatible with the Wordpress API,** but the only similar option is "in_same_cat" which is definitely not sufficient for this.

The basic query, in pseudo-sql, would be something like:

```
SELECT * from wp_posts where (insert custom arguments here)
   AND ID<(current post id)
   AND LIMIT=1
   AND ORDER_BY=ID
   AND ORDER=DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to change the posts that will appear in that "next/previous post" from the single template.
As far as I know, it uses the **post_nav_link** function (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link).
There are two ways to change this behaviour:

1. **Function Parameters**: As you can see on that link and in http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1636, you can try to use the parameters to ensure the behaviour you want.

but...

1. **Using filters**: Probably what you need is to use the filter **get_pagenum_link**. Using this filter you will be able to return the ID of the post you want to show. So just use the $wp_query or $post globals and help yourself.

If you need some help, just ask up, I'll be glad to help.